# Updating SimpleImage Class to resize animated .gif

Tags: php, gif, animated-gif

I am using Simon Jarvis' SimpleImage class to help with image manipulation on my site, and I need to resize animated GIF files with it.  The class is here:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php

I have a little bit in the loading which now determines if the file is an animated GIF, but that's about as far as I can figure out how to modify it.

Forgot to mention, I am not looking to convert the images from one file to another.  I want to display the re-sized image, but not save the file.